# Drawing vertical lines in between icons

Tags: html, css

Hello people am new to front end web development and still learning. I need to add two vertical lines in between three icons, please help me out.

This is what I've done so far:

```css
.photo {
  background-image: url(photo.jpg.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  color: hsla(325, 50%, 50%, 0.6);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15%;
}

.p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFCA28;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  color: hsla(325, 50%, 50%, 0.6);
}

.Request {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #d50000;
  float: center;
  margin-left: 22em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.q {
  float: right;
  padding: 2%;
}

.j {
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.icon1 {
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  font-size: 4rem!important;
  /* !important is here just to override SO styles*/
  color: #777;
  border: 2px solid #777777;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 6rem!important;
  /* !important is here just to override SO styles*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> JAMES UFONDU</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="q">
    Products Community Talk to Sales Request Demo En
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <h1> MANAGE YOUR CONDOMINIUM THE BETTER WAY</h1>
    <p class="p"> <strong>Use Evercondo to communicate, manage, organize, measure and optimize your day-to-day operations.</strong> </p>
    <p class="Request">Request Demo</p>

  </div>

  <div class="j">
    <h2> How does Evercondon Work ? </h2>
    <p>Eliminate the chaos in your day-to-day management tasks</p>
  </div>
  <div class="contentwrap">
    <i class="fa fa-car icon1"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star-o icon1"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-signal icon1"></i>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: by adding <hr> tag , you can add horizontal line

Comment: i think you need vertical lines

Comment: hello thanks so far, but what  u guys are suggesting is not what i need please check the link i shared and note the icons that appear first, then u will understand what i need.Thanks after all

Comment: which link dis u share ? i cant see it. can you comment ot here

Comment: https://files.slack.com/files-pri/TAUAH3FK9-FAUGQ5E4B/concept-pixels-2.jpg

Comment: this is the link pls try it out

Comment: Oh yeah i saw it, but i couldnt access this link, can you host your image somewhere else please . Here if possible https://imgbb.com/

Comment: it gives me error and says this "Don't have an account on this workspace yet?
Contact the workspace administrator for an invitation"

Comment: ok no problems let me see how to link the photo to you

Answer (score 1):

```
I added the <hr> tag between the icons

<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
         <title> JAMES UFONDU</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
       </head>
       <body>
           <div class="q">
        Products Community Talk to Sales  Request Demo  En
           </div>
           <div class="photo">
           <h1> MANAGE YOUR CONDOMINIUM THE BETTER WAY</h1>
           <p class="p"> <strong>Use Evercondo to communicate, manage, organize, measure and optimize your day-to-day operations.</strong> </p> 
           <p class="Request">Request Demo</p>

           </div>

         <div class="j">
           <h2> How does Evercondon Work ? </h2>
           <p>Eliminate the chaos in your day-to-day management tasks</p>
         </div>  
        <div class="contentwrap">
          <i class="fa fa-car icon1"></i><hr> 
          <i class="fa fa-star-o icon1"></i> <hr>
          <i class="fa fa-signal icon1"></i><hr>
        <div> 
        </body>
```

Comment: thanks guys so far for your support and quick response, but what you guys gave me is not actually  what i want. Please look at the link i shared in the question, take note of the first icons there and how they were placed thats what i want. But nevertheless thanks to you all.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap i tag in span and add this tyle

```
.contentwrap span {
      border-right: 1px solid black;
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 18px;
      margin-right: 15px;
    }
```

```css
photo {
  background-image: url(photo.jpg.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  color: hsla(325, 50%, 50%, 0.6);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15%;
}

.p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFCA28;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  color: hsla(325, 50%, 50%, 0.6);
}

.Request {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #d50000;
  float: center;
  margin-left: 22em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.q {
  float: right;
  padding: 2%;
}

.j {
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.icon1 {
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  font-size: 4rem!important;
  /* !important is here just to override SO styles*/
  color: #777;
  border: 2px solid #777777;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 6rem!important;
  /* !important is here just to override SO styles*/
}

.contentwrap span {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 18px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> JAMES UFONDU</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="q">
    Products Community Talk to Sales Request Demo En
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <h1> MANAGE YOUR CONDOMINIUM THE BETTER WAY</h1>
    <p class="p"> <strong>Use Evercondo to communicate, manage, organize, measure and optimize your day-to-day operations.</strong> </p>
    <p class="Request">Request Demo</p>

  </div>

  <div class="j">
    <h2> How does Evercondon Work ? </h2>
    <p>Eliminate the chaos in your day-to-day management tasks</p>
  </div>
  <div class="contentwrap">
    <span>
   <i class="fa fa-car icon1"></i>   
 </span>
    <span>
  <i class="fa fa-star-o icon1"></i> 
 </span>
    <i class="fa fa-signal icon1"></i>

    <div>
```

Comment: Space them out too

Comment: Done @StefanBob